# PHP + jQuery + MySQL async fetching data, script ends unexpected

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, polling

I'm trying to use jQuery's $.ajax() to GET a PHP page, on a based interval, which prints the latest enteries from a MySQL table. If there are new enteries, they are printed on the page, if not, "NaN" gets printed.

This is my PHP function which checks for new enteries: http://pastebin.com/R6NHDU3t 
This is the HTML + jQuery which checks for response from the above function(got it from some answer here on Stack): http://pastebin.com/myT7evAx

The idea is this: I access the HTML page, the jQuery inside is GET-ing the PHP page every 3 seconds, the PHP checkes for new enteries inside MySQL; if there are new enteries, they are printed on the PHP page and get fetched by jQuery, then appended into #messages, if not, "NaN" is printed(because of JSON, doesen't matter).

This works fine **if no new enteries are available**: every 3 seconds "NaN" gets printed on the page; some Live HTTP Headers:

```
http://localhost/handler.class.php?Q=comments&_=1348715334458

Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://localhost/live.html

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 27 Sep 2012 03:08:54 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.3.13
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.13
Content-Length: 15 <---- the "NaN", no new data
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=97
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

**If new enteries are made**, the script stopps appending "NaN"(doh, new data), and it hould append my new enteries, but the script stopps, no new data is appended and it **stopps making requests**. Here is the latest Live HTTP Headers log, showing the last request:

```
http://localhost/handler.class.php?Q=comments&_=1348715337473

GET /handler.class.php?Q=comments&_=1348715337473 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://localhost/live.html

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 27 Sep 2012 03:08:57 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.3.13
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.13
Content-Length: 3257 <-- new data, so it got the response, but stopped here. no appending, no more requests.
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=96
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

Why does it stop when `handler.class.php?Q=comments` returns new data?

Comment: Did you check your JS error console? probably something in the 'new data' response is triggering a bug that fatal errors your JS script, killing any further execution.

Comment: You refer to the json object parameters in your JS in a PHP way (square brackets), whereas dot-separation is used. Try `this.username` instead of `this['username']`. You can also skip the `parseJSON` function by telling the jQuery AJAX function to treat the response as json.

Comment: Haha! I was also printing out an un-jsoned array. The console gave me a hint: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data`. Thank you very much for your help!